# D7: filter fields in content type based on selected taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, entities

I am wondering if it is possible to display certain fields to users when they fill in a content type, based upon which taxonomy term they have selected prior in that same content type.

So for example, I have one generic NEWS content type, but it included several sub news categories. Say, I have made a NEWS vocabulary with 3 taxonomies, named: press, book, lecture. All three demand different information, thus different fields. Now I don't want to expose all these fields, but only those fields that are related to the taxonomy term one selected when filling in the content type.

Any pointers if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition.

[image]